# DELETING in view affects ORIGINAL TABLE

Tags: mysql, database, subquery

I was working on the Table-View queries and what I expected was removing/deleting in the View table should not affect my rows or columns in Original table.

Imagine we have a table 'city'. and created a View table using 'CREATE view vw_city as SELECT * from city ;'

the table has id, city names, economy, population.

Now, I deleted ID 1 using 'DELETE vw_city from where id=1;'

I was expecting that this should be affected only the view table but it also affected the original table.

Is there a way to keep the original table value?

Comment: *Is there a way to keep the original table value?* Yes (edit and make the view non-updatable), but you'll loose deletion from the view, it will be impossible.

Comment: A view is *not* a copy of your original data, by definition. If you want to work with a copy of your data, you could make a copy (e.g. a simple way would be to use  `create table tmp as SELECT * from city`).